# Java - 'this' operator

Tags: java, this, operator-keyword

I have a question about the this operator in Java. In the case where a programmer would write a code like this:

```
private int counter;

public Incrementor(int counter){
this.counter = counter;
}
```

Would it be better to avoid shadowing effect and go with this:

```
private int counter;

public Incrementor(int startValue){
counter = startValue;
}
```

Wouldn't the this operator make the this operator obsolete in future programming execrises?

Comment: You've asked 13 questions and you didn't accept any!

Comment: `this` is not an operator.

Comment: You might still have to write code like `if (someObject==this)...`, or refer to the `this` of an outer class from an inner class.

Comment: Question is nonsensical. How can 'the this operator make the this operator obsolete'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "this" keyword is very useful. Your example is clear, but imagine the situation in which you have to pass a self reference to another method of an external object.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a reference to the current object. In your example `this.counter` means the counter variable defined in the class and the method argument `counter` is a local variable for the constructor.

The main idea here is to explicitly mention that you are using the variable of the current object. So it improves readability and understandability of your code.

Also you should know that `this` is not an operator ... it's a reference to the *current object*.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is used in more scenarios:

- it allows differentiating local variables from fields
- it allows passing the object as argument to methods `foo.add(this)`
- it allows the current object to be referred from inner classes: `Outerclass.this`
- it is used to invoke other constructors of the same class: `this()`

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of preference, but most programmers prefer the convenience of using the same name. Is it difficult to remember to refer to the class variables with `this` ?

Comment: Things that most programmers prefer aren't necessarily great practices.

Answer (score 3):

There is no shadowing in your first example. `this` is a very clear way in order to refer to class variables.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, this is simply a matter of good programming practices when you are doing it for class variables.

A code like:

```
private int counter;

public Incrementor(int counter){
this.counter = counter;
}
```

vs.

```
private int counter;

public Incrementor(int startValue){
counter = startValue;
}
```

Extrapolate it to 10 lines, and the first one is much more readable. Moreover, it also makes refactoring code easier.

Otherwise, 'this' has a special significance. The 'this' keyword refers to the current object inside a class and falls in line with object-oriented principles. It can be extremely helpful and meaningful in case of getters and setters.

**Added:**

Once you start working with inheritance, you will notice another keyword called 'super' that can significantly differentiate between attributes that are inherited and ones that are local inside a class.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the first one.  It makes the code more readable.  <strike>Also you should name the method `setCounter()` as this also lends to readability</strike>.

Another unrelated point is to stick with the Java Coding conventions for naming methods as outlined in the `Methods` section [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

**Edit:** That wasn't a method was it.  Oops!

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Java Coding Conventions. I would recommend *starting* with the JCC and modifying them to suit your needs if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In small methods, it is often more clear to give arguments the same name as the members they will be assigned to. If you are working with a larger method, this could become confusing. But then you need to evaluate whether the right decision is to change the name of the argument(s) or to decompose the method into sub-functions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you need to pass the object itself. That's when you use `this`.

Comment: not if you have an argument with the same name as the field.

Comment: Using `this` to refer to a field is absolutely not redundant - the original question shows this.  Even if it were redundant, it would be helpful for code clarity.

Comment: Alright, alright, somehow I knew I would get flak for this. Then again, explicitly marking fields with `this` is something I only saw in Java; not in C++, and not in C#. I wonder why.

Comment: I was doing it in C++ twenty years ago. You don't see it so much in C++ because it has the : syntax for member initialization in constructors; which also dictates that members have different names from constructor arguments; which in turn tends to lead to a _ or m_ prefix on member variables; which in turn eliminates the requirement for disambiguation.