# New to Java: Class Constructed but Returning Null

Tags: java, class, null

**UPDATED CODE & OUTPUT BASED ON COMMENTS**

I think I'm finally getting this! But, my Super Class constructor is returning null even though it is defined. My text defines the superclass constructor with just Public Dog() ... but this returns an error in Eclipse when I try to run this and will not execute. It is picking up the initialization for my int variables defined in the Corgi class, but it is not even returning the constructor method for Dog in this. I have also tried changing my call from Corgi myDog... to Dog myDog but that did not resolve this error either.

What am I doing wrong?

Super Class: Dog
Child Class: Corgi
Main program: Driver

Code below:

```
DOG.JAVA

public class Dog {

// class variables
public String type;
public String breed;
public String name;
public String topTrick;

// constructor
public Dog(String dType, String dBreed, String dName) {
    this.type = "harvesting catepillars";
    this.breed = "Yorkie";
    this.name = "Fiesta";
}

// methods
public void setTopTrick(String trick) {
    topTrick = trick;
}

// method used to print Dog information
public String toString() {
    String temp = "\nDOG DATA\n" + name + " is a " + breed +
            ", a " + type + " dog. \nThe top trick is: " +
            topTrick + ".";
    return temp;
}

}
```

---

```
CORGI.JAVA


public class Corgi extends Dog {

// additional class variables
public int weight;
public int age;

// constructor
public Corgi(String dType, String dBreed, String dName, int pounds, int years) {

// invoke Dog class (super class) constructor
    super(dType, dBreed, dName);
    weight = 8;
    age = 5;
}

// mutator methods
public void setWeight(int pounds) {
    weight = pounds;
}

public void setAge(int years) {
    age = years;
}

// override toString() method to include additional dog information
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (super.toString() + "\nThe Corgi is " + age +
            " years old and weighs " + weight + " pounds.");
}

}
```

---

```
DRIVER.JAVA

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dog myDog = new Corgi("fuzzy demon", "PomChi", "Turbo", 8, 5);
    myDog.setTopTrick("barking at air");
    System.out.println(myDog.toString());
}

}
```

---

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
DOG DATA
Fiesta is a Yorkie, a harvesting catepillars dog. 
The top trick is: barking at air.
The Corgi is 5 years old and weighs 8 pounds.
```

Comment: The names of the members in class `Dog` are the same as the names of the parameters in the constructor for class `Dog`. Hence in the constructor you are assigning values to the constructor parameters and not to the class members.

Comment: If the constructor parameter names are different to the class member names, then the _**this**_ keyword is not required,

Comment: Either way - whether I change the params or use the this keyword, it is still only returning the constructor and not using what was defined in the creation of the object in the main Driver class?

Comment: Of-course not, because you aren't assigning the parameter values to the class members. You are assigning literal values. Try, for example in your `Dog` constructor: `type = dType`

Comment: @Abra  Thank you! I understand now.

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: Are you aware, that your code is still available through the [version history of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58127215/revisions)? And, by editing your code away, your question makes no sense anymore, even worse kind of invalidating existing answers. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/24160174)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 2):

`this` operator is missing to refer the context of your object access...

```
//DOG.JAVA
public Dog(String type, String breed, String name) {
     this.type = "harvesting catepillars";
     this.breed = "Yorkie";
     this.name = "Fiesta";
}
```

Comment: And the `this` **keyword** is required because... ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869257/java-this-operator

Comment: Clarification: it's required here because the parameter called "type" shadows the class field called "type" (and the same for the other parameters). When you just do `type = "harvesting catepillars";`, you are setting the variable bound to the parameter "type" instead of the class field.

Comment: I have implemented both comments - it now returns the constructor and is not taking what is in the parameters in the main code (ie: "fuzzy demon", "PomChi", "Turbo"). I have updated my post with the code & output as they are now.

Comment: @MykaThomas Update Dog constructor as,
    
public Dog(String dType, String dBreed, String dName) {
    this.type =  dType;
    this.breed = dBreed;
    this.name = dName;
}

Comment: @dSanders   That fixed it!! Thank you all!! Because this is a homework assignment, I'm going to delete all my code from here as a precaution. Thank you, ALL of this was extremely helpful!!

Comment: @MykaThomas You're welcome. Also, do note that `this` is not required in the constructor because the parameters of constructor and the instance variables have different names.

Comment: Thank you @dSanders I have made notation of this from working with Abra (above) and the link Mohamed shared. This was all so helpful! I despise the textbook that this course is using, it has been very shoddy in explaining some of these key concepts for Java! I'm sure I'll be back... :) Thank you again!